# Помогите с DNS серверами пожалуйста

Tags: dns

Есть домен на 2domains.ru
Сервер брал с firstvds.ru
Нужно привязать домен к серверу, и следовательно вопрос: какие DNS сервера прописывать в настройках?

Answer (score 1):

> Изменить NS’ы у регистратора домена на серверы имен FirstVDS: ns1.firstvds.ru и ns2.firstvds.ru

Во всяком случае так написано у них на сайте (статья «[Вопросы о доменных именах](https://firstvds.ru/technology/faq/domains)», раздел «Как привязать домен к серверу»).

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, нужно прописать ns1.firstvds.ru и ns2.firstvds.ru или настроить собственный сервер имен.

Подробнее о подключении домена к серверу читайте в нашей базе знаний: https://firstvds.ru/technology/faq/domains

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.